# How to scale same application but with different config

Tags: c#, .net, windows, amazon-web-services, .net-core

I have the following scenario:

I currently have a Windows Service Application which is developed in .NET which has 15 different instances, with each of them having their own seperate config file, and each of them is placed on their own AWS EC2 Windows Server.

But after doing it this way for so long, I really wonder if there's a better and faster way to scale this, than doing manual work of having an entire Windows Server just for a single .NET Application?

I've been searching but I can't seem to find if it's possible to have some kind of "Cluster", where I can deploy a total seperate instance of my application with it's own "config", whenever it's needed?

Comment: In the spirit of the question (finding a better way), lets get up to speed, why do you need 15? is this a resource problem, ie cpu? my spidey sense are tingling

Comment: @TheGeneral 15 is the number of customers who has their own instance of my application. It needs to run on 15 seperate instances incase something fails or needs to be scaled up (Which is why it's currently on 15 seperate servers). The question was if there was an easier way than having to create a whole EC2 just to run a single application.